# $U(n)$ is a compact group. Proof.

Tags: general-topology, lie-groups, compactness, unitary-matrices

Consider a unitary group $U(n)=\{A\in GL_n(\mathbb{C}):A^*A=I\}$. I want to show that $U(n)$ is a compact group. First, I can observe that $U(n)\subseteq M_n(\mathbb{C})$ i.e. it's a subspace of an Euclidian space $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ with a metric given by $d(A,B)=||A-B||$ where $||A||=\sqrt{\text{tr}(A^*A)}$ where $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is naturally isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^{n^2}$ where $\mathbb{C}^{n^2}\cong \mathbb{R}^{n^2}\oplus \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$. So, it's enough to show that $U(n)$ is closed and bounded.

To show that $U(n)$ is bounded, it's enough to show that the norm of all elements of $U(n)$ is bounded by some constant. Indeed, observe
$$||A||=\sqrt{\text{tr}(A^*A)}=\sqrt{\text{tr}(I)}=\sqrt{n}.$$
So, we can see that $||A||\leq n$ for all $A\in U(n)$. Therefore, $U(n)$ is bounded.

Next, let's show that $U(n)$ is closed. I want to take a direct approach. To show that $U(n)$ is closed, it's enough to show that it contains all its limit points. Indeed, consider some sequence of unitary matrices $\{A_n\}$ that converges to $A$. We want to show that $A\in U(n)$ i.e.
$$A^*A=I.$$
But, it follows from the following sequence of equalities
$$I=\lim_{n\to\infty}I=\lim_{n\to\infty}A^*_nA_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}(B^t_n-iC^t_n)(B_n+iC_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}(B^t_nB_n+C^t_nC_n)+i\lim_{n\to\infty}(B^t_nC_n-C^t_nB_n)=(*).$$
Where using the fact that the limit of a matrix is the limit of each individual component and the product rule, we will get that $(*)=A^*A$. Can I use this direct approach? Did I miss some small details?

Comment: $U(n)$ is the preimage of the unit circle under the determinant map, and thus closed.

Comment: @ElliotG yeah, I know that approach. I just tried to argue directly.

Comment: @ElliotG There's a lot of non-unitary matrices with determinant of module $1$.

Comment: @Gae.S.Yes, you're totally right. Never mind my comment then.

Comment: @user89898989 I "don't recall" any theorem stating that closed and bounded subsets of metric spaces are compact. Did you prove somewhere that $M_n(\Bbb C)$ is locally compact?

Comment: @Gae.S. oh, I will edit. Since we can realize $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ as a real vector space via the identification $M_n(\mathbb{C})\cong \mathbb{C}^{n^2}\cong\mathbb{R}^{n^2}\oplus \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$, then $U(n)$ is technically is a subset of Euclidian space. So, above is true for Euclidian space. However, I need to be careful with metrics I guess. Also, yes, you are right. Close and bounded does not work for a general metric space.

Comment: The continuity argument for closedness of $U(n)$ may be salvaged. Let $f:\Bbb C^{n^2} \to \Bbb C^{n^2}$ be given by $f(A)=A^*A$. Then $f$ is continuous and $U(n)= f^{-1}({\rm Id}_n)$.

Comment: Also, $U(n)$ is a topological subspace of the *normed* space $\Bbb C^{n^2}$, so Heine-Borel applies.