# U(n) is compact and algebraic, but not abelian—why not a contradiction?

Tags: abelian-varieties, linear-groups, compact-manifolds

the subgroup of unitary matrices $\text{U}(n) \subset GL(n, \mathbb{C})$ is compact and definitely algebraic, with an algebraic group law; on the other hand, it's *not* abelian. why is this not a contradiction, in light of the following facts?

- every *complete* variety with an algebraic group law is abelian (see e.g. [[Milne](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/AV.pdf), Cor. 1.4])
- *completeness* for varieties over $\mathbb{C}$ amounts to *compactness* in the complex-analytic topology (see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_variety));
- $\text{U}(n)$ is algebraic (determined by a determinant relation), with an algebraic group law (matrix multiplication), and is *compact* (see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3866486/un-is-a-compact-group-proof)).

these together should imply that $\text{U}(n)$ is abelian, which is clearly false. my best guess is that something is going wrong with completeness, and that this thing isn't actually complete.

what gives?

Comment: An abelian variety does not mean an abelian group.

Comment: $U(n)$ is algebraic over $\Bbb R$, most definitely not over $\Bbb C$ (complex conjugation is a no-no).

Comment: @Marius Complex tori are indeed abelian groups.

Comment: @TedShifrin got it. and $\text{GL}(n, \mathbb{C})$ _is_ algebraic, but not compact, yes?

Comment: Correct. :) Same for $O(n,\Bbb C)$.